# Postgres Exception - Internal Statement is right but Query Fails

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

I'm inserting a record into my DB using the following:

```
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;

        HashMap<String, Object> hoursMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();



        hoursMap.put("PLACE_ID", hours.getPlaceID());
        hoursMap.put("DAY", hours.getDayID());
        hoursMap.put("TIME_OPEN", hours.getTimeOpen());
        hoursMap.put("TIME_CLOSE", hours.getTimeClose());

        String insertStr = StatementCreator.insertQueryGenerator("HOURS",
                hoursMap);


        try {
            conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt = StatementCreator.createStatement(conn, insertStr, hoursMap,
                    false);

            returnVal = stmt.execute();
            ConnectionManager.closeStatement(stmt);
            System.out.println("Created");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            ConnectionManager.closeConnection(conn);
        }

        return returnVal;
    }
```

However, when running this I get the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "TIME_OPEN" is of
>   type time with time zone but expression is of type character varying
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.   Position: 71

What I can't figure out is why?  The reason I say that is if I go into debug mode and look at the internal prepared statement I see the following:

```
INSERT INTO "HOURS" ("TIME_OPEN","DAY","TIME_CLOSE","PLACE_ID")VALUES('11:30:00-0400',6,'23:59:59-0400',541)
```

I copy/paste this into my SQL Editor and it runs and inserts the record.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Why are they dates/times? What does `hours.getTimeOpen` return?

Comment: Perhaps my naming conventions aren't the best.  However, getTimeOpen gets me 11:30:00-0400  which is (11:30 AM with the GMT -4) which is how you would store it in the DB

Comment: That's not what I asked; what datatype does it return? You're trying to insert a time and you've got an error message that says you're inserting a string into a time with timezone datatype. I guess that these are declared as strings? Maybe they shouldn't be?

Comment: Well yes, they return strings in the format I mentioned.  I assumed this was the easiest way to insert a time with a timezone into the DB.  Instead of having to create a calendar object and set the offset every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle but decisive difference between a **string literal** and a variable of type `varchar`.

A string literal like `'11:30:00-0400'` has no type assigned to it. But your function obviously returns `varchar`, which is the same as `'11:30:00-0400'::varchar`.
Like the error message informs, you need to add an **explicit cast** in this case:

```
'11:30:00-0400'::varchar::timetz
```

Or, in your case probably:

```
hours.getTimeOpen())::timetz
```

(Not sure about the kind of syntax you use.)
Or have your function return the proper type to begin with.

#### Don't use `timetz`

As an aside, I would strongly advice against using `time with timezone` (`timetz` for short) at all. It's a logically broken type. Postgres only provides it for standard compatibility but advices against its use. I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES):

> To address these difficulties, we recommend using date/time types that
>   contain both date and time when using time zones. We do not recommend
>   using the type `time with time zone` (though it is supported by
>   PostgreSQL for legacy applications and for compliance with the SQL standard)

And [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html):

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the
>   definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.
>   In most cases, a combination of `date`, `time`, `timestamp without time zone`, and `timestamp with time zone` should provide a complete range of
>   date/time functionality required by any application.

Answer (score 1):

If you only store the time+timezone, without the date part, you should declare the data type at PostgreSQL's side as `timetz` (or `time with time zone`) not `timestamptz` (or `timestamp with time zone`).

Comment: Actually, `timetz` shouldn't be used *at all*. I provided a rationale in my answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, yeah... I do agree that `timetz` is a nonsense data type, specially when we are on day light saving time...